# Emails sent through Oracle losing dots(.)

Tags: oracle, email, smtp

I have an oracle procedure that sends emails and there are some inconsistencies happening with dots(.) in the messages.

The problem is that in this specific case the email body is being built as an HTML and there is a link in the body of the email message and one of the dots is being removed from this link. For instance xxx.xxx.xxx is showing in the email as xxxxxx.xxx. This results in the receiver being unable to access the wanted link.

During my research for solutions to this problem I stumbled on the section 4.5.2 of SMTP standard RFC2821 that says:

- When a line of mail text is received by the SMTP server, it checks
  the line. If the line is composed of a single period, it is treated
  as the end of mail indicator. If the first character is a period and
  there are other characters on the line, the first character is
  deleted.

But how do I deal with this in order to make the links in the emails work properly?

Below the code of the procedure used to send emails:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SEND_MAIL (p_from in VARCHAR2,
                                                p_to in VARCHAR2,  
                                                p_subject in VARCHAR2, 
                                                p_message in VARCHAR2)
IS
  lv_server      VARCHAR2(255) := 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
  lv_port        NUMBER(10)    := 25;
  lv_rcpt        VARCHAR2(255) := p_to;
  lv_from        VARCHAR2(255) := p_from;
  lv_subject     VARCHAR2(255) := p_subject;
  lv_message     VARCHAR2(20000) := p_message;
  lv_conn        UTL_SMTP.CONNECTION;
BEGIN

  lv_Conn := UTL_SMTP.Open_Connection(lv_server, lv_port);
  UTL_SMTP.Helo(lv_conn, lv_server);
  UTL_SMTP.Mail(lv_conn, lv_from);
  UTL_SMTP.Rcpt(lv_conn, lv_rcpt);
  UTL_SMTP.OPEN_DATA(lv_conn);
  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lv_conn, 'Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?' ||
                                UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.QUOTED_PRINTABLE_ENCODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(lv_subject))) ||
                                '?=' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);


  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lv_conn, 'MIME-version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lv_conn, 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);

  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lv_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable '|| UTL_TCP.CRLF);

  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lv_conn, 'From: ' || lv_from || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lv_conn, 'To: ' || lv_rcpt || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lv_conn,  UTL_TCP.CRLF);
  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA(lv_conn, UTL_ENCODE.QUOTED_PRINTABLE_ENCODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(Utl_Tcp.Crlf || lv_message)));
  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lv_conn, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
  UTL_SMTP.CLOSE_DATA(lv_conn);
  UTL_SMTP.QUIT(lv_conn);
END;
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample message that displays this problem? And which verssion of Oracle are you using? Sounds quite like bug 5015439, but not sure. Does removing the charset from the content type help?

Comment: Any message with dots. Like "..test" will be seen on the email as ".test". Oracle 11g. I tried removing the charset and it didn't solve the issue. For the links in the emails to work properly i had to remove all other dots of the mail and leave only the ones from the IP address. This is just to keep things running while i don't find a definitive solution.